# Chrome flashing visual artifact black grid

Tags: google-chrome, nvidia

Ever since a Chrome update about 2 months ago, Chrome has been consistently flashing visual artifacts resembling a black grid. The artifact typically appears only as a short flash, in varying locations of the screen, typically when I am switching tabs or a video autoplay pauses or begins, but sometimes also for seemingly no reason. I have reinstalled Windows, and tried multiple versions of Nvidia drivers, but the issue still persists. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Windows bug fixed in beta build 22635.2841 and canary build 26002.1010.

Occasionally checkered artifacts when using drawImage directly in the video.requestVideoFrameCallback callback:

- https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40735345#comment91

White/black checkerboard artifacts appear on webpages with a video since Chrome 115:

- https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40281472#comment29

Youtube, Discord, Visual Studio Code are flickering with black checkered squares/vertical lines. Partial solutions to this issue.:

- https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/youtube-discord-visual-studio-code-are-flickering-with-black-checkered-squares-vertical-lines-partial-solutions-to-this-issue.306623/post-5152420

Chrome based browser Artifact.:

- https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/526612/chrome-based-browser-artifact/